# Dual boot with persistence

Tags: kali-linux, dual-boot, tails-os

I've just installed Kali-Linux 2016.1 and Tails using the YUMI multiboot installer but how do I make a persistence drive for both the OS to save all my settings. I've made a "casper-rw" persistence volume but how do I configure it to work with Kali and Tails. Also, I've tried "easy2boot" with "RMprepUSB" to multiboot Kali and Tails but I was unable to create persistence volume for Tails.

Can anyone suggest how to configure a persistence volume for Kali and Tails?

Answer (score 2):

**Do these links help - Tails + persistence is not supported any more**

http://rmprepusb.blogspot.co.uk/2016/03/adding-tails-22-to-e2b.html
http://rmprepusb.blogspot.co.uk/2015/08/add-full-kali-or-multiple-linux.html
http://rmprepusb.blogspot.co.uk/2014/05/add-kali-linux-v107-luks-encrypted.html
http://rmprepusb.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/installing-kali-from-iso-located-on-e2b.html

Comment: Thanks, i'll give it a try.. also does it means I cannot multiboot kali and tails on the same USB drive?